# Make IntelliJ IDEA use public key authentication on Windows

Tags: git, ssh, intellij-idea, public-key

I'm an Eclipse user who's evaluating a switch to IntelliJ IDEA. I'm currently trying out IDEA 10.0.2. My operating system is Windows.

When working with Git over SSH, IDEA always asks me for password. I can't find any option in the settings to make it use public key authentication. As per [this post](http://blog.grumblesmurf.org/2010/10/using-ssh-private-keys-with-git-and.html), my key is in the `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` directory and my `HOME` variable points to the same directory as `USERPROFILE`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and Googling for more details hasn't produced any results. Does anyone have any idea how to make IDEA use public key authentication?

**EDIT**: My key is password-protected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your command line git uses public key auth, the same should work from IDEA. In the IDEA VCS settings switch SSH implementation from `IDEA ssh` to `native` so that the same SSH is used as when running command line git.

Comment: I just tried that, but it doesn't work. My key is password-protected and it seems that IDEA launches git in a windowless process, where it stops, asks for password and waits forever.

Comment: In this case you should configure your git to use TortoisePlink.exe as the ssh client, it will pop up a window asking for the password. Or you can use a key without password protection.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! For reference, to make that happen, I had to look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985074/how-do-i-set-git-to-use-plink-exe

Comment: One caveat I had to figure out (in connection with the SSH: "native", is that the msysgit install does store it's keys in a local <MSysGit-Installation-Root>\.ssh directory. so keys stores in $HOME\.ssh where not picked up.

Comment: i switched the ssh, but still IDEA doesn't ask me a passphrase! It just freezes after pull or push

Comment: [Relevant stuff](http://askubuntu.com/a/362287/69674); using `ssh-add` we can suppress git asking for the passphrase so that IDEA can access the repository without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version [as of April 29th, 2019], there is no option for `SSH executable` to switch SSH implementation. So, I followed the following steps on Windows 10:

1. Create an ssh-keypair (it can be created on Linux and copied onto windows machine)
2. Copy public SSH key contents to GitHub `Settings` -> `SSH and GPG keys` -> `New SSH key`
3. Copy private key to `C:\Users\<your-user-name>\.ssh\`