# Git pull from command line prompts for username and password

Tags: git, windows-7, batch-file, cmd

I am running

```
git pull
```

on a repository in command-line. It asks for username and password. When I complete them the pull is successful, but I would like to run git pull from batch file and I would like my batch file to provide the asked username and password. How can I run git pull from batch file if my username is myusername and my password is mypassword? I've tried with the following (in my batch file):

```
cd mylocation
git pull
myusername
mypassword
```

But this was not successful. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"
```

and it will remember your username and password after entering it once more.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still prompting for username and password

Answer (score 1):

I use putty pageant (Plink) as authentification deamon. Then you can load your key to pageant and then the authentification is working automaticly.

[Putty installer](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty-0.62-installer.exe)

The problem is then you have to reinstall your msysgit and during the installation you can select Tortoise Plink as deamon.

[Configure Git to use Plink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985074/how-do-i-set-git-to-use-plink-exe)

Perhaps its an option for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution now is to use the [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), from Microsoft.