# Not able to connect to bitbucket using SSH keys, but connecting through SourceTree is working

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree

I have generated SSH keys using PuttyGen (priavte key is saved as "private.ppk" under .ssh folder). I have added the public key to my organisation Bitbucket's SSH key section. If I try to do any git operations using SourceTree, its working fine. But If I try to do anything from GitBash or from IntelliJ Idea, it gives the following error

> git@bitbucket.companyname: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Used "SSH-2 RSA key" option when generating the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means your [`GIT_SSH` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985195/6309) does not reference [`plink.exe`](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/putty-plink-examples/) (assuming Windows here).

But another approach would be to generate your SSH key (without passphrase at first for testing) with openSSH instead of putty:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P"" -m PEM
```

That will generate the default `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` private/public key

Register the public key to your account, and try again.
Then make sure SourceTree is [configured to reference OpenSSH](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-plink-unkown-option-quot-p-quot/qaq-p/773421#M23450), not PuTTY.